# What type of ODE is this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation in question is $$y''+y'+\frac{1}{x^2}y=x.$$

It's obviously second order. I think it's non-linear because of the $x^{-2}y$ term, and is non-homogenous because of the $x$ term. So it would be a second-order, non-linear, non-homogenous differential equation? Is this correct?

Comment: It is linear, non-constant coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a second-order non-homogeneous linear ordinary differential equation with a regular singularity at $x=0$.

Comment: non-homogeneous